# Can Blender emulate Maya's hotkeys?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, add-on, workflow, shortcut

I am sure this question has been answered before I just can't find it anywhere on the net.

My question is-   I am a Maya user and Blender feels so foreign to me. Is it possible to make Blender's interactions behave more like Maya? Not the interface, but more like the hotkeys things like orbit, track, selection, snapping, play, pause, and rewind etc..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kind of, but if you plan on following blender tutorials, you'd be better off climbing the learning curve to learn Blender's hotkeys.

Blender doesn't have a one-to-one mapping with Maya commands, but you can find keymaps on line that do a fairly good job of mapping what can be mapped.  Here's one example:  [Maya Navigation Hotkeys for Blender 2.8 onward](https://www.artstation.com/marketplace/p/mX3n/maya-navigation-hotkeys-for-blender-2-8-onward-and-my-custom-setup)

You can find others if you search the web for "Blender Maya hotkeys".